# Pasar Informacion de Formulario 1 a Formulario 2 automaticamente con el ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hola buenas necsito saber como puedo pasar de formulario 1 me entrega un ID y necesito pasarle esa informacion  al formulario 2  mediante react  (borre url) lo que tenia pensador es guardar response.data en un state y luego enviarlo al segundo formulario o algo por el estilo cualquier tipo de ayuda seria buena o consejo

Datos de primer Formulario

```
 const  [datos,setDatos] = useState({
        fechaInicio: new Date(Date.UTC()),
        fechaTermino: new Date(Date.UTC()),
        latitudNorte:'',
        latitudSur:'',
        longitudOriente:'',
        longitudPoniente:'',
        emergencia:false
    })
```

Submit del primer formulario

```
const  SubmitHydro = ()=>{
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
      let data = new FormData();
      data.append('fechaInicio', datos.fechaInicio);
      data.append('fechaTermino', datos.fechaTermino);
      data.append('latitudNorte', datos.latitudNorte);
      data.append('latitudSur', datos.latitudSur);
      data.append('longitudOriente',datos.longitudOriente);
      data.append('longitudPoniente',datos.longitudPoniente);
      data.append('emergencia',datos.emergencia);

      let config = {
        method: 'post',
          maxBodyLength: Infinity,
          headers: { 
            'x-token': token, 
            //   ...data.getHeaders()
          },
            data : data
        };
      
        axios.request(config)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

datos del segundo formulario

```
 const [datosMdp,setDatosMdp] = useState({
        IDSolicitud:'',
        // fechaInicio: new Date(Date.UTC()),
        // fechaTermino: new Date(Date.UTC()),
        // latitudNorte:datos.latitudNorte,
        // latitudSur:datos.latitudSur,
        // longitudOriente:datos.longitudOriente,
        // longitudPoniente:datos.longitudPoniente,
        // emergencia:false,
        multViento:'',
        multCorriente:'',
        nroPart:'',
        coordParticulas:'',
        diferenciaHorario:'',
        radioOrigen:'',
        resolucionRadio:'',
        nroRepeticion:'',
        deltaRepeticion:'',
        capa:'',
        analisisDirecto:true, // boolean
        analisisDeterministico:true, //Boolean
        pendiente:'',
        intercepto:'',
        SDxy:'',
        areaEmergida:'',
        areaSumergida:'',
        cdObjetoEmergido:'',
        cdObjetoSumergido:'',
        analisisLeeway:true, //boolean
        randomWalk:''
    })
```

Submit Segundo formulario donde necesito los datos del primero me imagine que podria ser algo asi

```
     const SubmitMDP = () =>{

      let data = new FormData();
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
      data.append('IDSolicitud', datosMdp.IDSolicitud);
      data.append('fechaInicio', datos.fechaInicio);
      data.append('fechaTermino', datos.fechaTermino);
      data.append('latitudNorte', datos.latitudNorte);
      data.append('latitudSur', datos.latitudSur);
      data.append('longitudOriente', datos.longitudOriente);
      data.append('longitudPoniente', datos.longitudPoniente);
      data.append('emergencia', datos.emergencia);
      data.append('multViento', datosMdp.multViento);
      data.append('multCorriente', datosMdp.multCorriente);
      data.append('nroPart', datosMdp.nroPart);
      data.append('coordParticulas', datosMdp.coordParticulas);
      data.append('diferenciaHorario', datosMdp.diferenciaHorario); //Ojito
      data.append('radioOrigen', datosMdp.radioOrigen);
      data.append('resolucionRadio', datosMdp.resolucionRadio);
      data.append('nroRepeticion', datosMdp.nroRepeticion);
      data.append('deltaRepeticion', datosMdp.deltaRepeticion);
      data.append('capa', datosMdp.capa);
      data.append('analisisDirecto', datosMdp.analisisDirecto);
      data.append('analisisDeterministico', datosMdp.analisisDeterministico);
      data.append('pendiente', datosMdp.pendiente);
      data.append('intercepto', datosMdp.intercepto);
      data.append('SDxy', datosMdp.SDxy);
      data.append('areaEmergida', datosMdp.areaEmergida);
      data.append('areaSumergida', datosMdp.areaSumergida);
      data.append('cdObjetoEmergido', datosMdp.cdObjetoEmergido);
      data.append('cdObjetoSumergido', datosMdp.cdObjetoSumergido);
      data.append('analisisLeeway', datosMdp.analisisLeeway);
      data.append('randomWalk', datosMdp.randomWalk);

      let config = {
        method: 'post',
        maxBodyLength: Infinity,

        headers: { 
          'x-token':token, 
          // ...data.getHeaders()
        },
        data : data
      };

      axios.request(config)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log((response.data));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer mediante la URL con un parametro y mediante la llamada del componente y reciviendolo con props

---

**URL** al llamar al siguiente componente, lo que haces el redirigir al usuario a una url relativamente diferente, a la que le agregas

> ? nombreParametro = valorParametro

Y si quieres agregar mas, vas agregando con

> & nombreParametro = valorParametro

`https://example.com/?name=Jonathan&age=18`

Lo puedes realizar con `window.location.replace(<url>?parametro=valorParametro)` Esto remplazará la ruta del usuario con una nueva, en este caso sería al moverte de componente. [Mas información](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace)

O usando `.set()` [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/set)

En la carga del siguiente componente puedes obtener los parametros con `.get(<nombreParametro>)`

[Mas información](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get)

```
let name = params.get("name"); // Este devuelve "Jonathan"
let age = parseInt(params.get("age"), 10); // Y este te obtiene 18
```

---

**PROPS**

En tu componente principal solo agregas los nombres y sus valores

```
<Pay price={ 50 } discount ={ 5 } cards={ 3 } />
```

Y en tu siguiente componente solo lo recibes como:

```
const Pay = (props) => {
    const { price, cards, discount } = props;
    //Usa las variables como te convengan en tu componente
}
```

Espero estos resuelvan tu duda, te incentivo a que investigues un poco antes de consultar :D así como desarrolladores también nos acostumbramos a revisar documentación y estar listos para una siguiente vez que nos suceda.